# UserName in Google Provisioning api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-provisioning-api

i am developing an app.i am using google provisioning api in this app.in documentation it is mentioned that for getting information related to a user account we have to pass a parameter userName in url

```
GET https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/user/2.0/userName
```

i am logged in an application i can get his email address ,his Id using basic profile info api (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={accessToken})but how to get userName of the logged in user .please some one help!!

Answer (score 0):

Google provisioning API is only available to Google Apps user (Google Apps domain user), not for personal account.  [2Legged Oauth](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/articles/2lo-in-tasks-for-admins)1.0 should be used on authentication, Not Oauth 2.  Not clear about what's your situation.